# Arduino and Bluetooth USB dongle

Tags: arduino, usb, bluetooth

Is it possible to use a mini USB Bluetooth dongle like in the following picture in order to improve my [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno), so it can comunicate with other Bluetooth devices?

[image]

If it is, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, in theory, possible, to make your Arduino talk USB to the Bluetooth dongle. Usually, however, the better solution is to buy a serial-to-bluetooth module, and connect that to the serial pins on your Arduino, or to pins on Arduino compatible usable by the SoftwareSerial library.

Comment: Thanks man. I will seek more a obut this topic. May be I can even open the USB dongle and take out the things I need.

Comment: @user1754322 - That's unlikely. Most of those USB-bluetooth adapters have pretty much just one IC in them, that does everything. Also, the RF layout is pretty touchy, so you can't easily just breadboard it.

Answer (score 3):

No, the Arduino Uno can not use the Bluetooth dongle for two reasons:

- To use an USB peripheral device such as the dongle, the Arduino would need to be a USB [***host mode***](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/USBHost), or USB ***OTG*** mode device. The Uno does not support host or OTG mode, though the [Arduino Due](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue) and the [Arduino ADK](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK) do.
- To support a Bluetooth dongle, you also need a "Bluetooth stack" on the host that supports a dongle. While there are some efforts out there to design such an open source stack for the Arduinos that support Host Mode, and possibly for "USB host shields", there isn't anything stable for USB dongles, that I know of, yet.

---

**USB Host Shield:**

[image: USB Host Shield]
(*[source](http://www.circuitsathome.com/products-page/arduino-shields/usb-host-shield-2-0-for-arduino/)*)

Note that such shields usually do not have support for generic USB Bluetooth dongles. If there are some which do, a link would be interesting.

---

Your other options are to either **acquire one of those Arduino models** that do support Host Mode, then experiment with the Bluetooth stacks available for it, or to **use a Bluetooth module** such as the [Bluetooth Bee](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Bluetooth_Bee), or **[shields incorporating Bluetooth](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Bluetooth_Shield)**, and use those.

**Serial Bluetooth Shield:**

[image: Bluetooth Shield] (*[source](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Bluetooth_Shield)*)

**The Bluetooth Bee:**

[image: Bluetooth Bee] (*[source](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Bluetooth_Bee)*)
*Requires a shield that supports the Zigbee type pin-out. Note that the Xbee pins are not the common 0.1 inch spacing, but a less common 1 mm spacing.*

Shields that support ZigBee format modules:

[image: Wireless SD shield] (*[source](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWirelessShield)*)
[image: Seeed Studio XBee Shield] (*[source](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/XBee%C2%AE_Shield)*)

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are a really, **really** awesome programmer, you could *probably* use a plain-old arduino to bit-bang a USB host. However, if you're that skilled of an embedded programmer, you probably wouldn't need to ask if it were possible.

Comment: @ConnorWolf There you go :-)

Comment: You are right :). Anyway, it is never late to learn. Thanks!

Comment: @user1754322 I believe the accepted answer is incorrect, thereby.