# Interfacing barcode scanner with microcontroller

Tags: usb, rs232

I am doing a project involving barcode scanner, netduino plus 2(microcontroller). I came across different types of interfaces(pin standard used such as USB etc..) for barcode scanners which are Keyboard wedge, RS232, USB (which again acts as keyboard wedge or RS232). I shortlisted datalogic QW2170 (barcode scanner) which supports both USB and RS 232. The USB interfacing is of plug-n-play type. I was wondering if i can use USB (use usb cable from barcode scanner to connect to netduino plus 2) interfacing to capture the stream of data coming from barcode scanner after scanning barcode (to be specific 1D barcode) and save it in the microsd card (netduino plus 2 has a slot for microsd card upto 2 GB) or do i need to use a RS 232 interfacing for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

For receiving USB input from the barcode scanner, your microcontroller board must support **USB host mode**, or **OTG mode** (USB On The Go, which can be switched between Host and Device mode). The Netduino Plus 2 does not have a host-mode USB interface.

Instead of the Netduino, consider using a microcontroller board which does support host-mode or OTG USB.

Alternatively, use the RS232 interface of the scanner, level shift the voltages as required, and use standard serial input on the MCU board.

---

*See also [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/60758/14004), for more information and some options on USB Host Mode / OTG, albeit in the context of the Arduino, not the NetDuino.*

Comment: As stated i used RS232 interface of scanner (Datalogic QD2100), but a new problem arises. The manual given with this barcode scanner has certain barcodes for mode setting (scan mode-flashing, scan mode-always ON etc), restoring default settings, select interface. The output of the barcode scanner is a female RS232 and so i used a male RS232-usb converter cable to connect it to my laptop. I installed the driver which came with RS232-usb converter cable and also installed the software which was sent to me regarding barcode scanner.

Comment: continued-I have set the com port to COM1 and opened word. 
My cursor was placed in the word and when i do scan any barcode it doesn't show up on word. 
I used RS232 interface selection (using the barcode provided in the manual) first time and as i did not get any data in my word i used usb interface selection and that too didn't work.

Comment: @SainathMacharla New problem, new question please.